# System hangs with ESET NOD32 Antivirus and Windows 7 from VHD

Tags: windows-7, vhd, nod32

I've installed the latest version of ESET NOD32 Antivirus Home Edition 4.0.468 onto a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate (x86). Windows boots from a VHD file (I suspect this is the problem). After installing NOD32, the system hangs when attempting to use Windows Explorer (or a minute or so after boot-up). The problem disappears when I uninstall NOD32. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring NOD32 Real-Time Scan to ignore .VHD files seems to do the trick. So far, no hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this. I have a VHD running Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) with the latest NOD32 (x64) and it doesn't freeze. Sorry, Jacob.

Comment: Odd, I was under the impression that only Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise supports booting from VHD. I have replicated the problem on Windows 7 Ultimate RTM (x86) on two different PCs with different hardware, and I still get the same result. However, on a PC that boots directly from a partition, exact same setup, doesn't freeze.

Comment: Typo - I have Ultimate (x64). I reckon you should accept your own answer about ignoring the VHD files.